# Testing the normality and correlation of the feature and label values

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, data-visualization

I have a dataset which is being stored in a 2D `numpy` array. I want to test the normality and correlation of each feature which is a column of the array and then plot it.

I know that using R, it can be easily done by running the following commands:

```
shapiro.test(Class$Feature)
ggqqplot(Wage$age, ylab = "Feature")
```

And again in R the correlation test can be done easily by running the following command:

```
res <- cor.test(Class$Feature, Class$class, method = "pearson")
```

How can I do these steps in python?

I tried `Scipy`'s Normaltest with multi-columns dataset as below but id didn't work.

```
from scipy import stats
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
k2, p = stats.normaltest(df[:,1], df[:,5]) #Testing Feature 1 agains Feature 5
print (p)
```

Comment: regarding Pearson,  does using `corrcoef` (from `numpy` for example) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I noticed that using `numpy` array may not be an appropriate approach to solve this issue. That's why I loaded my data set in a `pandas` Data Frame and then used the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import shapiro
import pylab
import scipy.stats as stats
def test_normality(data_frame, features, feature_for_test):
    for feature in features:
        print("Test Result: " + str(shapiro(data_frame[feature])))
        stats.probplot(data_frame[feature], dist="norm", plot=pylab)
        pylab.show()

test_normality(data_frame, ["feature1","feature2", "feature3"], "feature_for_test")
```

And for correlation test I used the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
def correlation_test(data_frame, features, feature_for_test):
for feature in features:
    cor, _ = pearsonr(data_frame[feature], data_frame[feature_for_test])
    print("Pearson Correlation Test Result: %.3f" % cor)

correlation_test(data_frame, ["feature1","feature2", "feature3"], "feature_for_test")
```